# Limit max result with Spring boot pagination

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to fetch limited amound of search result but still use of pagination. When I use next line in my repository class I get 100 result on the page.

```
Page<Media> findTop100ByOrderByViewCount(Pageable pageable);
```

If I use next line instead, then I get expected result with according to my pageable which is 10 item on each page.

```
 Page<Media> findAllByOrderByViewCount(Pageable pageable);
```

I want to limit the search result. If there are 1000s of search result, I don't want to have 100s of paginated result. I want to limit my paginated limit to have max 10 page.

How can I achieve that in Spring boot? I'm using version of **2.2.2.RELEASE**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this in Spring Data.

You can wrap the call to the repository and replace the `Page` you receive with a modified one, which limits the total amount to `10*pagesize` and removes the `next` value for page number 10. And probably skips the call to the database completely if the pagenumber is greater 10.